# Why does this code break when -O2 or higher is enabled?

Tags: c, clang, pic, microchip, xc8

I tried to fit an implementation of NSA's [SPECK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speck_(cipher)) in a 8-bit PIC microcontroller.
The free version of their compiler (based on CLANG) won't enable optimizations so I ran out of memory. I tried the "trial" version that enables -O2, -O3 and -Os (optimize for size). With -Os It managed to fit my code in the 2K program memory space.

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

#define ROR(x, r) ((x >> r) | (x << (32 - r)))
#define ROL(x, r) ((x << r) | (x >> (32 - r)))
#define R(x, y, k) (x = ROR(x, 8), x += y, x ^= k, y = ROL(y, 3), y ^= x)
#define ROUNDS 27

void encrypt_block(uint32_t ct[2],
        uint32_t const pt[2],
        uint32_t const K[4]) {
    uint32_t x = pt[0], y = pt[1];
    uint32_t a = K[0], b = K[1], c = K[2], d = K[3];

    R(y, x, a);
    for (int i = 0; i < ROUNDS - 3; i += 3) {
        R(b, a, i);
        R(y, x, a);
        R(c, a, i + 1);
        R(y, x, a);
        R(d, a, i + 2);
        R(y, x, a);
    }
    R(b, a, ROUNDS - 3);
    R(y, x, a);
    R(c, a, ROUNDS - 2);
    R(y, x, a);

    ct[0] = x;
    ct[1] = y;
}
```

Unfortunately, when debugging it line by line, comparing it to the [test vectors in the implementation guide](https://nsacyber.github.io/simon-speck/implementations/ImplementationGuide1.1.pdf), from page 32, "15    SPECK64/128 Test Vectors", the results difer from the expected results.

Here's a way to call this function:

```
uint32_t out[2];
uint32_t in[] = { 0x7475432d, 0x3b726574 };
uint32_t key[] = { 0x3020100, 0xb0a0908, 0x13121110, 0x1b1a1918 };

encrypt_block(out, in, key);

assert(out[0] == 0x454e028b);
assert(out[1] == 0x8c6fa548);
```

The expected value for "out", according to the guide, should be `0x454e028b, 0x8c6fa548`. 
The result I'm getting with -O2 is `0x8FA3FED7 0x53D8CEA8`. 
With -O1, I get  `0x454e028b, 0x8c6fa548`, which is the correct result.

**Step Debugging**

The implentation guide includes all the intermediate key schedule other values, so I stepped through the code line by line, comparing the results to the guide.

The expected results for "x" are: `03020100`, `131d0309`, `bbd80d53`, `0d334df3`. I start step debugging, but when reaching the 4th result, `0d334df3`, the debugger window shows `0d334df0` instead. By the next round, the expected `7fa43565` value is `7FA43578` and only gets worse with every iteration.

This only happens when -O2 or greater is enabled. With no optimizations, or with -O1, the code works as expected.

Comment: TL;DR: undefined behaviour in your code. start by protecting your macros arguments by parentheses. when using `i + 2` not sure it does what you want.

Comment: I see the problem. When OP posts the inputs used and a  [MCVE], it will be obvious.

Comment: @chux is there other than the "macro argument not parenthesized"?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala "macro argument parenthesized" would be better form, yet I think OP escaped that pitfall luckily here.  Yet without `[MCVE]` OP is making this harder than it needs to be.

Comment: because the only argument which has 2 terms is used for the eoring `x ^= k` so it works. But leave the parentheses from now on.

Comment: but but, your inputs are `char` pointers and your function accepts pointers on integers. Don't you have warnings? it's an alignment issue.

Comment: alignment errors, strict aliasing violations and whatnot

Comment: and endianness :) compilers tend to move/align variables according to optimization levels. I'm not going to answer this to get "UB points" as Antti likes to call them :)

Comment: casting to uint32_t* suppresses the errors but the results are the same. Endianness is not an issue here, because I manually checked the endianness, and if it was actually an endianness issue, it would also fail with -O0 or -O1

Comment: "casting to uint32_t" how do you do this? can you show us?

Comment: it's not an issue with endianness, but don't write code like that as it is not portable on other processors with different endianness

Comment: casting to `uint32_t *` does not fix the error. In any case, I get it behave in "expected" manner with *that* hideous call without casts and anything with -O3 on my x86-64... `-fsanitize=undefined`, valgrind, etc... result `8b 02 4e 45 48 a5 6f 8c`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I'm working with 256 BYTES of RAM. Not 256K, but 2^8 bytes. For my whole program. Certain concessions need to be made.

Comment: try with little-endian `uint32_t`s: `0x7475432d, 0x3b726574`; `0x3020100, 0xb0a0908, 0x13121110, 0x1b1a1918`; the result should be `0x454e028b, 0x8c6fa548`

Comment: you just have to read the comments properly to know what the issue is: don't declare your data as pointers on `char`. The compiler will assume that it can put them in unaligned memory locations. And please be nice. There's no elitism here.

Comment: It *can* be a compiler bug too.

Comment: true as clang early versions weren't very good.

Comment: `uint32_t out[2]; uint32_t in[] = { 0x7475432d, 0x3b726574 }; uint32_t key[] = { 0x3020100, 0xb0a0908, 0x13121110, 0x1b1a1918 };`

Comment: also change `i` to `uint32_t`.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala with your suggestions, the results are the same as mine. Fine with -O1, but breaks with -Os. The results are the same. The bad result with uint32_t is 0x8FA3FED7   0x53D8CEA8 and with a char array is 0xD7 0xFE 0xA3 0x8F 0xA8 0xCE 0xD8 0x53. At least the results are consistent...

Comment: Minor: use `unsigned i` to quiet a distracting warning in `for (int i = 0; i < ROUNDS - 3; i += 3) R(b, a, i); ....` as the `R()` then mixes sign-ness.

Comment: To rule out a bug I think my only other option is to find their previous version of the compiler. This is 2.0.5, based on Clang. The 1.45 version was a different compiler. Unfortunately the company has pulled 1.45 from their website.

Comment: It does not appear `"speck.h"` is needed here.  If it has something _interesting_, let us see it, else better to remove it.

Comment: @chux, you mean the rewrite of R? I just tried it. Same wrong result with -Os. I'm really starting to think this is a compiler bug.

Comment: I am leaning towards a compiler bug here if the code as it is now in the question with all `uint32_t`s etc still produce the same behaviour. No other plausible explanation comes to mind...

Comment: UB can occur from _other_ un-posted code.  We do not see how OP fed `encrypt_block(out, in, key);` nor reported its output.  Hopefully the missing code is benign, yet it is remains unknown.

Comment: IIUC, the output comes from the debugger. But then again, the *debugger might be wrong*.

Comment: @hjf can you do asserts in the controller? Or sth like set a variable for `int flag = (out[0] == 0x454e028b && out[1] == 0x8c6fa548)` and act on `flag` to ensure that it is not the debugger that's the issue?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Agreed, With optimizations, results needs to be truly _used_ as output, else it may be optimized away and the debugger can report garbage - perhaps consistent garbage.

Comment: As posted here, `encrypt_block()` is not the problem.

Comment: Updates: I managed to find the previous version of the compiler... deeplinked to the manufacturer's website from a dodgy chinese site. Anyways, same error.  I also did volatile int flag = (out[0] == 0x454e028b && out[1] == 0x8c6fa548) (the compiler never optimizes volatile). The result was zero. Also volatile uint32_t  r1=out[0];
volatile uint32_t  r2=out[1];. r1 and r2 are the usual "right with O1, wrong with O3".

Comment: @hjf Re: "I'm really starting to think this is a compiler bug" Could be.  Yet UB cased by the calling code remains a possibility.  For the record, what is `int/unsigned`  bit size here?  `UINT_MAX`?

Comment: @chux how could be the reason here? 27 should fit into an `int` and it should be correctly promoted anyway..

Comment: @chux see here for the compiler manual on int types https://i.imgur.com/2MsC05s.png

Comment: @AnttiHaapala The reason for `int/unsigned` inquiry is not due to the `for()` loop.  As `unsigned` is 16-bit (much code is faulty with 16-bit) and prior code was loose on pointer usage, these 2 hint to calling code woes.  Also I wanted to review this code with non-32-bit `int` in mind if warranted.

Comment: @hjf Since, under some conditions, code get the expected result, try `#define ROUNDS 0`, `#define ROUNDS 3` and/or maybe `uint32_t in[] = { 0 }; uint32_t key[] = { 0} ` to close in on the culprit.  Good luck!

Comment: Not related to the bug, but your size problem could probably be fixed by getting rid of the awful manual unrolling and writing the loop directly. It would also deobfuscate it quite a bit.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include disassembly of the compiler output for this function at both -O1 and -O2 optimization settings. Looking at what machine code the compiler is actually generating is by far the easiest way to figure out where the problem is in your C code. I'd obtain the disassembly myself, but this is a proprietary compiler that you're using.

Comment: Update: I have asked the question in the manufacturer's website. Other people have reproduced the issue and confirmed it is actually a bug. It happens with PIC16 parts but not with PIC18. As a workaround, I replaced the macro with an actual function, and did the (x >> r) | (x << (32 - r)) operation in two steps: x = x >> r; x |= x<<(32-r); This seems to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***It was a bug in the compiler.***

I posted the question [in the manufacturer's forum](https://www.microchip.com/forums/m1089410.aspx). Other people have indeed reproduced the issue, which happens when compiling for certain parts. Other parts are unaffected.

As a workaround, I changed the macros into real functions, and split the operation in two lines:

```
uint32_t ROL(uint32_t x, uint8_t r) {
    uint32_t intermedio;
    intermedio = x << r;
    intermedio |= x >> (32 - r);
    return intermedio;
}
```

This gives the correct result.

Answer (score 2):

Posting compilable test code as a reference.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
//#include "speck.h"

#define ROR(x, r) ((x >> r) | (x << (32 - r)))
#define ROL(x, r) ((x << r) | (x >> (32 - r)))
#define R(x, y, k) (x = ROR(x, 8), x += y, x ^= k, y = ROL(y, 3), y ^= x)
#define ROUNDS 27

void encrypt_block(uint32_t ct[2], uint32_t const pt[2], uint32_t const K[4]) {
  uint32_t x = pt[0], y = pt[1];
  uint32_t a = K[0], b = K[1], c = K[2], d = K[3];

  R(y, x, a);
  // for (int i = 0; i < ROUNDS - 3; i += 3) {
  for (uint32_t i = 0; i < ROUNDS - 3; i += 3) {
    R(b, a, i);
    R(y, x, a);
    R(c, a, i + 1);
    R(y, x, a);
    R(d, a, i + 2);
    R(y, x, a);
  }
  R(b, a, ROUNDS - 3);
  R(y, x, a);
  R(c, a, ROUNDS - 2);
  R(y, x, a);

  ct[0] = x;
  ct[1] = y;
}

int main(void) {
  uint32_t out[2];
  uint32_t in[] = {0x7475432d, 0x3b726574};
  uint32_t key[] = {0x03020100, 0x0b0a0908, 0x13121110, 0x1b1a1918};
  encrypt_block(out, in, key);

  printf("%8lx %8lx\n", (unsigned long) out[0], 0x454e028bLU);
  printf("%8lx %8lx\n", (unsigned long) out[1], 0x8c6fa548LU);
}
```

Output

```
454e028b 454e028b
8c6fa548 8c6fa548
```

Unexpected output

```
0x8FA3FED7
0x53D8CEA8
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any indication of undefined behavior in your code, unless it's in some aspect of the setup/call point that you haven't shown. As such, it should be impossible for behavior to differ according to optimization level. Normally I would not be quick to blame compiler bugs for something like this, but forks of FOSS compilers for embedded stuff, and especially forks that redefine `int` to 16-bit in a compiler that wasn't designed to target 16-bit `int`, and especially proprietary forks where their code is so bad that they don't even want to let you see it, a compiler bug is very very likely.